# How to get rid of specific TableView Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, uitableview

My tableview is populated with cells that show an item with its name, price, and brand. Some objects that I get from the web service return , and that looks ugly on the table view cell. I don't want to populate table view cells that have a price of "null". Here is my code so far. For now, I change it to say "Price Unavailable".

```
   for (NSDictionary *objItem in resultsArray)
{
     NSString *currentItemName = [objectTitlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([currentItemName isEqualToString:objItem[@"title"]])
    {
        if (cell.priceLabel.text != (id)[NSNull null] && cell.priceLabel.text.length != 0 && cell.brandLabel.text != (id)[NSNull null] && cell.brandLabel.text.length != 0)
        {


        cell.nameLabel.text = currentItemName;

            NSDictionary *bestPageDictionary = objItem[@"best_page"];

            NSNumber *price = bestPageDictionary[@"price"];

            if ((cell.priceLabel.text = @"<null>"))
            {
                cell.priceLabel.text = @"Price Unavailable";
            }

            else
            {

            cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", price];
            }


            NSArray *brandsArray = objItem[@"brands"];
        cell.brandLabel.text = [brandsArray firstObject];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is terribly inefficient. You are keeping the JSON (I'm assuming) return in a dictionary, then looping over the dictionary for EVERY cell that you're creating. Not only that, you aren't cleaning up the JSON ahead of time.

It's much more expensive to create a useless cell then go back and try to delete it. In your `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate, you've already told the `tableview` that you have X many cells. Now you're trying to delete the cells which will mess up the callbacks. You'd have to create a method that will run after you finish creating all cells that will then loop through all your cells to delete them from the tableView, which will then call `[table reloadData]`. However, because you actually aren't removing the data from the `NSDictionary`, you actually will create the same amount of cells again and be stuck in an infinite loop.

***Solution:***

First, change your structure. Once you get the JSON return, sanitize it to delete all values with no price. I suggest also using an object class to hold each server object. This will simplify your code a lot for the TableView as well as other classes as well. Now that you've cleaned up your return, change it from a `NSDictionary` into a `NSMutableArray`. Then in `numberOfRowsInSection:` you call `[array count]`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you simply look at `[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get your object.

You'll want code to generally look like:

```
ServerItem.h : NSObject{
  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* name;
  ...
  add in other properties here
}


- (NSMutableArray *) parseJSON:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict{
  NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSArray *dictArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:jsonDict[@"results"]];
  for (NSDictionary *itemDict in dictArray)
  {
    NSDictionary *bestPageDictionary = objItem[@"best_page"];
    if (![bestPageDictionary[@"price"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"]])
    {
      ServerItem item = [ServerItem new];
      item.price = ...
      item.name = ....
      [returnArray addObject:item];
    }       
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```

Inside your webService code:

```
self.itemArray = [self parseJSON:dataDictionary];
```

Then

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.itemCallArray count]    
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...
  ServerItem *cellItem = [self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.nameLabel.text = cellItem.name;
  cell.priceLabel.text = cellItem.price;
  ...

}
```

Comment: So I create a method before numberOfRowsInSection with a for loop that runs through all my cells and only returns cells that HAVE  price?

Comment: Sorry, but could I perhaps see a code example to get me started?

Comment: No - when you get your web service return, loop through the NSDictionary to remove all bad objects from it. You want to sanitize your data before you try to create cells. The point of this is that you should never delete cells because of bad data. Post your web service return parsing code.

Comment: Let me know if what I posted makes sense - it requires you restructuring your code but it will make it a lot cleaner, efficient, readable, and object oriented. It introduces you using an object `ServerItem` to store your return from the server. Now you don't have to keep an array of item titles, then parse on the fly for the cells. You have the upfront parsing then everything is created/sorted for you into an array of `ServerItems`. Then when you create cells, it's very easy to access each one and their properties.

Comment: So the parseJSON method goes after the call? but then how do I get the dataDictionary array if I'm doing it outside of the call

Comment: Do it inside the method right after you create dataDictionary. I didn't know your method name so I said to just put it inside your webService code :)

Comment: actually i was talking about the -(NSMutableArray*)parseJSON method. how do i use the dataDictionary method when it's outside my call method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56447/discussion-between-lyricalpanda-and-doc92606).